# How to show error message in the form

Tags: javascript, php

For the login screen, I have done some small validation.
Now the problem is I don't know how to bring the validation error msg

Please refer the else section, where the error message is mentioned.

Eg: Error message is "Invalid Username and Password Combination" when the user provides invalid username and password

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="icon" type="img/png" href="pic/logo3.png">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body id="loginform">
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass =$_POST['pass'];

$query      = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM admin_user WHERE name='$name' and pass='$pass'") or die(mysqli_error());
$row        = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

if ($row) 
{           

if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
setcookie('name', time()+60*60*7);
}
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
header('location:index.php');
}
else
{

echo '<div class="col-sm-12 text-align--center error">'.'Invalid Username and Password Combination'.'</div>';
}

}
?>
<div class="col-sm-6 align-center loginForm">
<img src="pic/logo.png">
<div class="box">
<form action="" method="post" name="login" class="boxContent">
<label>Username</label><br>
<input class="login-input" type="text" name="name" /><br>
<label>Password</label><br>
<input class="login-input" type="password" name="pass" /><br>
<input class="login-input m-bottom" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
<input class="bump-left" type="checkbox" name="remember"><label>Remember me</label><br>
</form><br>
<div class="forgot">
<a class="bump-left" href="">Forgot Your Password?</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-pad--none">
<div class="bgcontent"><img src="pic/services2.jpg"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: `mysqli_error()` requires the connection - `mysqli_error($conn)`.

Comment: Assign the error message to a variable and then echo that variable in the location you wish it to appear.

Comment: You just checked form submission. I didn't see your code for validating name and pass

Comment: i can assign a variable and echo but the problem when i do this is, it will always be invoked in the  place where i echod

Comment: i need this error only when my username and password is wrong

Comment: mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM admin_user WHERE name='$name' and pass='$pass'")

Comment: it check the match between username and password and log in

Comment: You are also mixing procedural and Object Oriented styles

Comment: Could not understand what you need since you already have the error message at the top. It's not showing you the error message?

Comment: it is showing at the top of the page... but i need it under my form

Comment: @mishal you have answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Please read the comments above from Jay and take them into consideration and apply what is suggested as it is very important in securing your
>   application**

Now back to your question you need to store the error message in a variable then just echo that variable where you want the message to show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="icon" type="img/png" href="pic/logo3.png">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body id="loginform">
<?php

$loginError = "";
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass =$_POST['pass'];

$query      = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM admin_user WHERE name='$name' and pass='$pass'") or die(mysqli_error());
$row        = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

if ($row) 
{           

if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
setcookie('name', time()+60*60*7);
}
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
header('location:index.php');
}
else
{

$loginError = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-align--center error">Invalid Username and Password Combination</div>';
}

}
?>
<div class="col-sm-6 align-center loginForm">
<img src="pic/logo.png">
<div class="box">

    <?php echo $loginError;?> <!-- error will display here -->
<form action="" method="post" name="login" class="boxContent">
<label>Username</label><br>
<input class="login-input" type="text" name="name" /><br>
<label>Password</label><br>
<input class="login-input" type="password" name="pass" /><br>
<input class="login-input m-bottom" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
<input class="bump-left" type="checkbox" name="remember"><label>Remember me</label><br>
</form><br>
<div class="forgot">
<a class="bump-left" href="">Forgot Your Password?</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-pad--none">
<div class="bgcontent"><img src="pic/services2.jpg"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit :**

Putting everything together from the users comments above :

> [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says your script is at risk for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/php).
>   Learn about prepared statements for MySQLi. Even escaping the string
>   is not safe! Or PDO,

To solve the above you need to use prepared statements, you have two options, 1 use mysqli prepared or use PDO prepared statements,  there are many arguments as to which one is better than the other comparison available on the internet, [quick comparison here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison)

I honestly prefer PDO.

> **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's built-in functions to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version
>   less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` compatibility pack.
>   Make sure you don't escape passwords or use any other cleansing
>   mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and
>   causes unnecessary additional coding.

Therefore a solution for the above is to use `password_hash()` and `password_verify();`

See more about [password hash and verify here](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) :

So what you need to do now when you inserting the data in your database from the register page, you need to have a hash

```
$hash = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT); Then you will need to store the hashed password in the database which is `$hash()`
```

This is how you login should look with PDO and `password_verify()`

```
<?php
session_start();

/*PDO Connection*/
$host    = 'localhost';
$db      = 'YOURDATABASE';
$user    = 'root';
$pass    = 'YOURPASSWORD';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $LoginMessage = "";

    $stmt    = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin_user WHERE name = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$name]);
    $results = $stmt->fetch();

    if ($results && password_verify($_POST['pass'], $results['pass'])) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
        header('location:index.php');
    } else {
        $loginError = "<div class=\"col-sm-12 text-align--center error\">Invalid Username and Password Combination</div>";
    }
}

?>
<div class="col-sm-6 align-center loginForm">
<img src="pic/logo.png">
<div class="box">

    <?php echo $loginError;?> <!-- error will display here -->
<form action="" method="post" name="login" class="boxContent">
<label>Username</label><br>
<input class="login-input" type="text" name="name" /><br>
<label>Password</label><br>
<input class="login-input" type="password" name="pass" /><br>
<input class="login-input m-bottom" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
<input class="bump-left" type="checkbox" name="remember"><label>Remember me</label><br>
</form><br>
<div class="forgot">
<a class="bump-left" href="">Forgot Your Password?</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-pad--none">
<div class="bgcontent"><img src="pic/services2.jpg"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank u masivuye cokile and  Jay Blanchard for helping me

Answer (score 0):

/* please try below working sample code, I have added some security patches too */

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";  /* database name */
$errorMessage = "";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['name'])) : ""; /* Escapes special characters in a string */ 
    $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['pass'])) : "";  /* Escapes special characters in a string */ 
    if($name != "" AND $pass != ""){ /* check name and pass for not empty */
        $query      = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM admin_user WHERE name='$name' and pass='$pass'") or die(mysqli_error());
        $row        = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        if ($row){
            if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
                setcookie('name', time()+60*60*7);
            }
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            header('location:index.php?sdfsdf');
        }else{
            $errorMessage = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-align--center error">Invalid Username and Password Combination</div>';
        }
    }else{
        $errorMessage = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-align--center error">Invalid Username and Password Combination</div>';
    }
}
echo $errorMessage;  /* place it anywhere you want */
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this?. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Even [escaping strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of echo, you should pass the message into a variable, such as:

```
$tempMessage = "Invalid Username and Password Combination";
```

And then on your HTML

```
<?php if (isset($tempMessage)) : ?>
    <div class="yourClass">
        <?=$tempMessage?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Or you can store it in a Session variable, so that you can count bad login attemps, and etc.